# Awk-like BEGIN and END with Ruby command-line

Tags: ruby, unix, command-line, awk

One of the cool things about Ruby is its ability to behave like typical Unix command-line tools, to do things like (similar to the example from the official documentation):

```
$ echo "matz" | ruby -pe '$_.upcase!'
MATZ
```

Awk, on the other hand can perform an aggregation on lines from standard input, e.g., summing a sequence of numbers:

```
$ for (( i=0; $i < 50; i++ )); do echo $i; done | awk 'BEGIN { tot=0; } { tot += $0 } END { print tot }'
1225
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to get Ruby to do what is being achieved by the Awk `BEGIN` and `END` blocks above so as to be able to do similar aggregation operations.

Comment: Is `BEGIN` and `END` required in this code example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
seq 49 | ruby -pe 'BEGIN { $tot=0 }; $tot += $_.to_i; END { print $tot }'
```

Comment: I've copied this verbatim to the command-line, but it doesn't work.  Do I need a minimum version of Ruby?

Comment: I use ruby 1.9 here and there's no 1.8 binary in archlinux. Try with 1.9 - it's out some years now. ;-)

Comment: I'm using 1.8.7 (Cygwin), and noticed that if I changed `tot` to `$tot` everything works.

Comment: Looks like there are some scoping differences between 1.8 and 1.9 :-)

Comment: Try adding a trailing "\n" to see it more clearly. END { print $tot , "\n" }

Answer (score 3):

Actually ruby has `BEGIN`/`END` block support as well. e.g. see this blog post: http://burkelibbey.posterous.com/rubys-other-begin

Some more documentation: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UA

HTH